Query builder - last online 15 mins interval bug
I'm creating an api that fetches the latest logged in users.
if a filter param is true - filter to show online users only
if (Boolean.parse(isOnline)) {              
    filterConditions += ` AND u.lastLoginAt < NOW() - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE`;
}

but there appears to be a bug in this sql - where its returning all loggedin marked members , not just the ones that logged in only 15 mins ago?
-
is there an issue with the greater than formula here -- is NOW() not getting the latest timestamp? is it because 15 is coded as a string?
SELECT u.* 
FROM application.users_tbl u
WHERE u.role = 'user'
  AND u.lastLoginAt < NOW() - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
ORDER BY u.createdAt DESC;



Which dbms are you using? (NOW() is a product specific function.)

Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve], where you use properly formatted text for sample data and expected result (i.e. no images.)

Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. And please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Not sure what you mean - the sql is provided in text - but how else would I sample just the loginAtDate col - to show that 4 results are coming back, when really only 1 should show

They meant: What implementation of SQL are you using. There are dozen of different popular SQL based databases.

Just standard mysql - although I feel my error was because of GMT being in summer time etc.. so although 15 seemed the right interval - it would be more like 75 in mine. I wasnt sure though how to keep 15 as the number but change the query to be strict about summertime changes

I think you just should invert condition to >
AND u.lastLoginAt > NOW() - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
            


if I do that - no results show -

Like would "NOW() - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE" -- revert to a same date/timestamp in the same format as the lastLoginAt date?

This answer is correct. If no results are shown, this is very likely because nobody logged in in the last 15 minutes.

No its as if in my version it returns results that have a lastLoginAt stamp - other profiles that dont ignored... - I am running locally so thats when I first noticed its returning previously logged in accounts - but not the one that was just 15 mins ago - but all

I've made a fiddle of it - https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=a594dd73-bb9a-48a6-a23b-e54c38942635

I think one of the problems I am having is how the server is storing the data - as if its GMT summer time -- so although I put 15 mins - I really should put 75 -- to make up for  the data difference - whats the best way of addressing this?

Rule of thumb: always use UTC time when you store it, and convert it to local time zone only upon display to users!
And putting 75 minutes offset would break season change.

"always use UTC time when you store it" - how do you do that -and also is there a way of ensuring the NOW() is using UTC?

IDK what dbms you are using. I assume you are using MySQL as it's popular starter choice.
it's UTC_TIMESTAMP()  in postgres you have specific data type timestamptz  or you can use NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
I'd suggest to read what is UTC and how to use it properly. You would need to handle it on java side as well.
Whenever I start a new project I'm making sure that DB server runs in UTC, so even regular timestamp would be in UTC by default. but timestamptz is safer.
